# Changing file path in .dpr file in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

We are using Delphi 6. Currently, we have kept all the different application folders under one main folder.

We have below folder path for one of the applications:

```
C:\dev_GIT\MyApplications\Delphi\Sales_Applications\Member_Joining
```

For some reason, we would like to move this folder to below folder path:

```
C:\dev_GIT\Member_Joining
```

Issue we are getting is that we have some common files which are kept in separate folders and which are used in so many other applications as well.

Since we are moving this folder outside of the current folder path, we are getting compile error, which is expected.

The real issue is, as there are so many files which are in common folder path, we need to change their path in .DPR file one by one. Is there any better way by which we need not to change path for all the files in the .DPR file?

Comment: Change the paths using a text editor's search and replace facility. Although personally I wouldn't hard code paths at all, but you seem to prefer to do that.

Comment: This is why you should always use relative paths, which Delphi does by default. It takes a user to change it to absolute paths.

Comment: I was also planning the same. But just thought that there may be some other way. Many Thanks.